# Prove that $\int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]} f(x,y) \,dA$ doesn't exist. I cannot prove this.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am watching a [lecture](https://youtu.be/exmZ4nuWGM4?t=2940) on multivariable mathematics by Theodore Shifrin on YouTube.

> Let $R:=[0,1]\times[0,1]$.
> Let $f:R\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x,y) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{q} & (x=\frac{p}{q}, y=\frac{s}{q}, \frac{p}{q}\text{ and }\frac{s}{q}\text{ are irreducible fractions}),\\
> 0 & (\text{otherwise}).
> \end{cases}$
> Prove that $\int_{R} f(x,y) \,dA$ doesn't exist.

I must prove that for some $\epsilon_0 >0$, there doesn't exist a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $R$ such that $U(f,\mathcal{P})-L(f,\mathcal{P}) < \epsilon_0$.
In other words, I must prove that there exists some $\epsilon_0 >0$ such that for any partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $R$, $U(f,\mathcal{P})-L(f,\mathcal{P}) \geq \epsilon_0$.
But I cannot prove this.

If $f$ were defined as follows, I could prove that $\int_{R} f(x,y) \,dA$ doesn't exist.
I quess that Professor Shifrin intended the following $f$ since this $f$ is much easier for his purpose.
But I am interested in my question itself now.

> Let $f:R\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(x,y) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 1 & (x=\frac{p}{q}, y=\frac{s}{q}, \frac{p}{q}\text{ and }\frac{s}{q}\text{ are irreducible fractions}),\\
> 0 & (\text{otherwise}).
> \end{cases}$
> Prove that $\int_{R} f(x,y) \,dA$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you compute $U(f, \mathcal{P})$? It might help to draw the graph of your function.

Comment: I edited my question. The definition of $f$ was corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't prove it because the integral exists.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$ and pick $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N+1} \leqslant \varepsilon$. The set $$F = \left\{ \frac{p}{q} : 0 \leqslant p \leqslant q \leqslant N \ \& \ \frac{p}{q} \text{ is an irreducible fraction} \right\}$$ has some finite cardinality $s$. Take $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{s^2}{M^2} \leqslant \varepsilon$ and consider the partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $R$ into squares of side length $\frac{1}{M}$. It suffices to prove that $U(f, \mathcal{P}) \leqslant 2 \varepsilon$.

We have that $$U(f, \mathcal{P}) = \sum_{S \in \mathcal{P}} \frac{1}{M^2} \cdot \sup_{z \in S} f(z).$$

Divide $\mathcal{P}$ into subsets $\mathcal{P}_1$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ where $\mathcal{P}_1$ consists of squares which intersect $F \times F$ and $\mathcal{P}_2$ of the remaining squares. Then $|\mathcal{P}_1| \leqslant s^2$, so

$$\sum_{S \in \mathcal{P}_1} \frac{1}{M^2} \cdot \sup_{z \in S} f(z) \leqslant \frac{s^2}{M^2} \cdot 1 \leqslant \varepsilon.$$

For $S \in \mathcal{P}_2$ we have that $\sup \limits_{z \in S} f(z) \leqslant \frac{1}{N+1} \leqslant \varepsilon$, hence

$$\sum_{S \in \mathcal{P}_2} \frac{1}{M^2} \cdot \sup_{z \in S} f(z) \leqslant \frac{M^2}{M^2} \cdot \varepsilon = \varepsilon.$$

Therefore

$$U(f, \mathcal{P}) = \sum_{S \in \mathcal{P}_1} \frac{1}{M^2} \cdot \sup_{z \in S} f(z) + \sum_{S \in \mathcal{P}_2} \frac{1}{M^2} \cdot \sup_{z \in S} f(z) \leqslant \varepsilon + \varepsilon = 2 \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Adayah, Thank you very much for your proof (the integral exists!).

Answer (score 0):

Given any partition of the unit square you have $$U(f,\mathcal{P})=1$$ and $$L(f,\mathcal{P}) =0$$
For $U(f,\mathcal{P})$ you pick rational points and for $ L(f,\mathcal{P})$ you pick irrational  points so you have $$U(f,\mathcal{P})-L(f,\mathcal{P}) =1 $$

Comment: Mohammad Riazi-Kermani, I am very sorry. The definition of $f$ was not right. I corrected  the definition of $f$.

Comment: With the new definition of  $f$ the proof by Adaya is very nice.